# Why is the edge of this pixel-perfect rectangle in Illustrator still fuzzy?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a simple rectangle that is totally aligned to the pixel grid. Position X, Y and width and height values are all whole integers. I've also checked the 4 corner vertices which are all definitely on pixel intersections.

[image: Rectangle]

Yet in Pixel Preview, it still has a fuzzy bottom edge – what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't really resolve this, except to note that the fuzzy border only appears when the rectangle is behind another section of the graphic which had some opacity effects turned on.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the object doesn't have any effects applied to it like a stroke, a drop shadow, outer glow, things like that. Or that may actually be another object below the darker box.